# Scala error: object XML is not a member of package org.json on Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to execute the followng scala code but I keep on getting the following error:

command-3313750897057320:1: error: object XML is not a member of package org.json

The full error looks like the following:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
import org.json.XML
import scala.util.Try

val parseXmlToJson = udf((value: String) => 
                         try{
                             XML.toJSONObject(value).toString
                         }
                         catch{
                           case e: Exception => "Processing Error"
                         }
                        )
  // Defined UDF to parse xml to json

spark.udf.register("XmlToJson", parseXmlToJson)
```

The objective of the code is to convert/parse XML to JSON.

Comment: Do you have `java-json.jar` on your classpath? org.json.XML could be imported iff you have the mentioned jar in your classpath.

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal, sorry for the delayed response. I added the java-json.jar to my classpath as you suggested and it solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: great! Happy to help. Have added it in answers below, please mark it as solution so that someone else can find the solution for the same issue if they come across sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `java-json.jar` to classpath should fix the issue. `org.json.XML` could be imported if and only if the mentioned jar is added to classpath.